# Left Joining Table with Sum - Causing Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to Left Join Multiple tables with two sum columns that both join on a mid step table.

The tables look like:

**Table1**

```
ID  Value1
1   3
2   2
3   3
```

**Table2**

```
ID  Value1
1   5
2   2
3   2
4   1
```

**Jointable**

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I'm trying to output:

```
Table1Value1SUM Table2Value1Sum
8 | 10
```

With the SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Value1) Table1Value1SUM,SUM(Table2.Value1) Table2Value1Sum From Table1
Left Join JoinTable
On JoinTable.ID = Table1.ID
Left Join Table2
On Table2.ID = Table1.ID
```

I'm getting these results:

```
Table1Value1SUM Table2Value1Sum
8 | 9
```

Comment: It's been mentioned in the answers, but your join table has absolutely nothing to do with your question.  Furthermore, join tables have at least two columns: the PK from one table - and the PK from another (hence the term: 'join table').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jointable` has to be `left join`ed upon with the other 2 tables.

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Value1) Table1Value1SUM,SUM(Table2.Value1) Table2Value1Sum 
From JoinTable 
Left Join Table1 On JoinTable.ID = Table1.ID
Left Join Table2 On JoinTable.ID = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`Left Join` the `Table2` with `JoinTable` instead of `Table1`

```
SELECT SUM(Table1.Value1) Table1Value1SUM,SUM(Table2.Value1) Table2Value1Sum From Table1
Left Join JoinTable
On JoinTable.ID = Table1.ID
Left Join Table2
On JoinTable.ID = Table2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

What has jointable to to with this? You want the sums of table1 and table2, hence:

```
select
  (select sum(value1) from table1) as table1sum,
  (select sum(value1) from table2) as table2sum
```

or

```
select t1.table1sum, t2.table2sum
from
  (select sum(value1) as table1sum from table1) t1
cross join
  (select sum(value1) as table2sum from table2) t2;
```